# Probability problem 2

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are 10 boxes each containing 6 white and 7 red balls. Two random
boxes are chosen, one ball is drawn simultaneously at random
from each and transferred to the other box. Now a box is again chosen
from the 10 boxes and a ball is chosen from it. Then the probability
that this ball is white is

(A) 6/13 (B) 7/13 (C) 5/13 (D) none of these.

My attempt: There are 3 cases of transfer 1) White White Transfer
2)Red-Red Transfer
3)White Red Transfer

The probability for the cases 1 & 2 will be (1/10)*(6/13). 
The probability for 3rd case is 2/10*((7/13)+(5/13))+(1/8)*(6/13)
Total Probability= Probality for case 1+ Probability for case 2+ Probability for case 3 = 0.33 which comes to none of this.The correct answer is A) 6/13 .
Where I am going wrong.I think I cannot evaluate the probability for 3rd case correctly.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

There are $130$ balls in total that have equal chances to be drawn. $60$ of them are white.

Comment: How would you justify the 'have equal chances to be drawn' claim? I'm afraid it isn't obvious to me.

Comment: @TamojitMaiti If you fix some ball then you can construct a calculation of the probability that it will be drawn. Now fix another ball. Again a calculation of the probability that it will be drawn can be constructed. But will this calculation differ from the first? Definitely not. So they will have the same outcome.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's look at the transfers.

$P(WW) = P(W)P(W) = (\frac{6}{13})^2$

$P(RR) = P(R)P(R) = (\frac{7}{13})^2$

$P(WR) = P(W)P(R) = (\frac{6}{13})(\frac{7}{13})$

$P(RW) = P(R)P(W) = (\frac{6}{13})(\frac{7}{13})$

These sum to 1, so we're in good shape.

After this transfer step, we either have

1. 10 boxes with $6$ white and $7$ red balls (since the WW and RR transfers don't change anything) with Probability $P(WW)+P(RR)$
2. 8 boxes with $6$ white and $7$ red balls, 1 box with $7$ white and $6$ red balls, 1 box with $5$ white and $8$ red balls with Probability $P(WR)+P(RW)$

These are the two scenarios you are sampling from. Your final probability of getting white $P$ is now:

$P = P($scenario 1$)P($selecting white in scenario 1$) + P($scenario 2$)P($selecting white in scenario 2$)$.

It's clear that in scenario 1, that since each box is the same the probability of selecting white is $\frac{6}{13}$. Calculating scenario 2, you should find that it will also come out to $\frac{6}{13}$!

Thus your end result will be $\frac{6}{13}$, and the transfer, in fact, made no difference (see hint from @drhab).